# bodyWithPolygonFromPath:path Crashes App

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I using this code to create a Volume based physics body

```
    // Add a physcis body to the largeRock by creating a path
    CGFloat offsetX = largeRock.frame.size.width * largeRock.anchorPoint.x;
    CGFloat offsetY = largeRock.frame.size.height * largeRock.anchorPoint.y;

    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 12 - offsetX, 57 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 0 - offsetX, 48 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 0 - offsetX, 21 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 0 - offsetX, 21 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 21 - offsetX, 0 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 39 - offsetX, 0 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 60 - offsetX, 9 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 60 - offsetX, 39 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 48 - offsetX, 57 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 12 - offsetX, 57 - offsetY);

    CGPathCloseSubpath(path);

    largeRock.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithPolygonFromPath:path];
```

This works fine on the simulator, but when i test it on the iPad the app crashes when the "largeRock" is added to the scene

The last line is were is crashes.
When I change "bodyWithPolygonFromPath" to "bodyWithEdgeLoopFromPath", the app runs fine, but then the sprite is not affected by gravity or any other physics because it now an Edge based physics body.

Since i need the largeRock to be affected by gravity, I am at a loss for what to do.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does the app crash "when the largeRock is added to the scene" or on the "last line" in your code?

Comment: Whoops! Sry, forgot to add that. It crashes when the largeRock added to the Scene

Answer (score 0):

You have two points in the path that are identical, at least the duplicate point not at the end points of the path needs to go.

Also if the path isn't a convex shape hat might also cause a crash.

Comment: The duplicate point should be removed, but it's not the cause of the crash.